# php - show variables in echo

Tags: php, variables, echo

I want to submit some form information using POST method. On submit i want to verify those choises with a php file. I have the following code

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];

echo "<h2>Your Choices:</h2>";
echo "<table class=\".2\">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>$name</td>
        </tr>

        </table>";
?>
```

The problem is that when i submit the form, the php file loads perfect, but the variables value ($name) is not visible. The tale just shows $name as text.

What am i doing wrong? i've tried many variations, using .$name. etc but nothing works...

Thanks

Comment: might be `$_POST["name"]` is empty

Comment: Can we get a bit more (neater) code?  How are you assigning a value to `$name`?

Comment: What's the value of $_POST['name'] ? Could it be $name?

Comment: and where's the form for this?

Comment: `class=\".2\"`? what's that?

Comment: [*"The tale just shows $name as text."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

As I can assume, your code just display `<td>$name</td>` instead of variable value.

You can use variables in this way:

```
echo("<td>" . $var . "</td>")
```

Comment: Why would you assume that? (What does assuming do?) Have you tested the OP's code? `echo` does not need parentheses and all variables are interpolated in double quotes. Read the code in the original question again - the variable will work perfectly in this situation as long as it is not empty. The OP actually has *another* problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the $_POST values may be not correct.  I would change the code to dump the POST values, and simply echo the one value in your code, e.g.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
$name = $_POST["name"];
?>
<h2>Your Choices:</h2>
<table class=".2">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><?= $name ?></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously you'll want to remove that print_r once you have solved the problem.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question though, does it? Look at what the OP is saying carefully.

Comment: Thanks guys but nothing of these works... :/